# Neo4j merge performance

Tags: neo4j

I have a data import engine that queries API's for social data, and processes it into Neo4j

I'm using a MERGE query to create/update UserActivity nodes, and relating them to Contact's, as follows:

```
MATCH 
  (profile:SocialProfile {profile_id:20})-[:`RELATES_TO`]->(user:Contact) 
MERGE  
  (user)-[r:`USER_ACTIVITY`]->(activity:UserActivity {useractivity_id: '20_532181000298962040'})
ON CREATE SET
  r = {is_new: true, date_created: '2014-11-11 16:03:05'},
  activity = {date: '2014-11-11 14:40:12', text: 'hi man hope all is well!', user: '{"identifier":289883222,"displayName":"foomanchu","profileURL":"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/foomanchu","photoURL":"http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/474234438473353985\\/Rbp-7K33_normal.png"}', to: null, to_id: null, type: 'feed', relates_to: null, num_replies: null, num_likes: null, num_retweets: 1, num_favorites: 3, is_liked: false, is_favorited: false, author_self: null, media_type: 'link', media_embed_url: "http://ow.ly/Ez3Dt", media_action_url: "http://ow.ly/Ez3Dt", remote_uid: 532181000298962040, useractivity_id: '20_532181000298962040', service: 'Twitter', datetime: 1415716812, author_remote_uid: 289883222}
ON MATCH SET
  activity = {date: '2014-11-11 14:40:12', text: 'hi man hope all is well!', user: '{"identifier":289883222,"displayName":"foomanchu","profileURL":"http:\\/\\/twitter.com\\/foomanchu","photoURL":"http:\\/\\/pbs.twimg.com\\/profile_images\\/474234438473353985\\/Rbp-7K33_normal.png"}', to: null, to_id: null, type: 'feed', relates_to: null, num_replies: null, num_likes: null, num_retweets: 1, num_favorites: 3, is_liked: false, is_favorited: false, author_self: null, media_type: 'link', media_embed_url: "http://ow.ly/Ez3Dt", media_action_url: "http://ow.ly/Ez3Dt", remote_uid: 532181000298962040, useractivity_id: '20_532181000298962040', service: 'Twitter', datetime: 1415716812, author_remote_uid: 289883222}
```

Some notes:
- We're talking about a DB with 500k nodes, so it's really small.
- Takes about 1,000MS on a cloud server with digital ocean (8 GB RAM, 4 Cores)
- On my 1+year old laptop, in a VM with 1.5 GB RAM, it takes about 350ms (still slow but not as slow).
-I'm not sure why the discrepancy since the other server is (in theory) far more powerful.
-In both environments the databases are identical (zipped up data folder and copied it over prior to tests), yet there are significant discrepancies in speed.

I'm wondering a couple of things:
1. Is there anything I can do to optimize the queries? I already have Indexes on profile_id and useractivity_id
2. Any practical hardware/JVM/neo4j performance suggestions? I'm struggling with the Neo4J documentation on performance tuning guide.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there are a couple of things you can do :

1. What is your indexing strategy ? Do you have the SocialProfile-profile_id property indexed ?
2. Use query parameters, so the cypher query can be cached independtly of the passed parameters
3. for the first match, you can match first the socialprofile alone, using label+indexed property profile_id and then match the pattern to user :

   MATCH 
   (profile:SocialProfile {profile_id:20})
   WITH profile
   MATCH (profile)-[:`RELATES_TO`]->(user:Contact)
   ...

Chris